# Convert flux value in nmol/min/mg protein to nmol/min/cell?

Tags: biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics, kinetics, units

This is a question about unit conversion. I found an experimental measurement of the saturation uptake of glucose in yeast:

$$V_\textrm{max} \approx 650 \textrm{nmol}/\textrm{min}/\textrm{mg protein}$$

See Table III of [Diderich et al. (1999)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10336421)<sup>*</sup>. Actually the paper reports a range of measurements, I just picked an intermediate value.

> Table III
>
> Maximum velocity (nmol·min<sup>−1</sup>. mg protein<sup>−1</sup>) and Michaelis constant (mm)
> of glucose transport by cells grown in aerobic glucose-limited
> chemostats at various dilution rates and in batch culture on glucose

I want to convert this to nmol/min/cell, that is, to units of flux per individual cell.

These are my **questions**:

1. What exactly is the meaning of the units reported? 
   It wasn't very clear to me after reading the paper, so I suppose these are standard units. I presume that "mg protein" refers either to the milligrams of transporter protein, or to the total cellular protein content, but I don't know which.
2. If that's the case, what's the advantage of these units instead of
   grams of dry weight (which I think are more common)?
3. Finally, how can I convert this to flux per cell?

---

<sup>*</sup> Diderich, Jasper A., et al. "[Glucose uptake kinetics and transcription of HXTgenes in chemostat cultures of Saccharomyces cerevisiae.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10336421)" *Journal of Biological Chemistry* 274.22 (1999): 15350-15359.

Comment: I think the reported unit refers to the maximum specific activity of the enzyme.

Comment: @WYSIWYG So you guess that the "mg protein" refer to "mg of enzyme", not total protein content?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I read the experimental section in more detail. They determine "protein content" using the biuret protein assay, which I looked up and I *think* only determines the *total* protein content. That is, it is not specific to a particular protein. But I am not sure, and I still think this is a weird way to measure it? Isn't gDW better?